# Inkscape deletes some curves

Tags: inkscape

I am facing a weird problem with Inkscape. It is a bit vague so please bear with me.
I created a drawing and exported it as PNG. I am not sure what I did next but a few lines disappeared. Of course the first thing I did was undo. Didn't work. As you can see clearly below the nodes are still there but lines are not visible.

[image]

Worst part is this. I had checked in the svg in github. I thought I could just it check out and everything will be back to normal. Not to be.

Even worse part is that this is the second time this has happened to me. I definitely
need to understand what I am doing wrong and how to restore the drawing.

Update: I found a solution myself. As seen above there are two outline layers. I was working on Outline2. The older layer "Outline" had some rough lines and I had hidden it. I did not really need it any more. So I just deleted it. Voila! My lines are back. But I still don't understand what happened.